# Numpy 1 Degree of Freedom

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

In the following code I'm confused as to what the third line means. What does the ddof = 1 do. I tried looking it up, but I still don't quite understand the concept or the purpose. I would really appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

```
data = stats.binom.rvs(n = 10, p = 0.3, size = 10000)
print "Mean: %g" % np.mean(data)
print "SD: %g" % np.std(data, **ddof=1**)
```

Answer (score 3):

Degrees of freedom is an important concept which you may want to [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)), but the computational difference is actually straight forward, consider these:

```
In [20]:

x = np.array([6,5,4,6,6,7,2])
In [21]:

np.std(x)
Out[21]:
1.5518257844571737

#default is ddof=0, what this actually does:
In [22]:

np.sqrt((((x-x.mean())**2)/len(x)).sum())
Out[22]:
1.5518257844571737
In [23]:

np.std(x, ddof=1)
Out[23]:
1.6761634196950517

#what ddof=1 does:
In [24]:

np.sqrt((((x-x.mean())**2)/(len(x)-1)).sum())
Out[24]:
1.6761634196950517
```

In most languages (`R`, `SAS` etc), the default is to return std of ddof=1. `numpy`'s default is ddof=0, which something worth noting.

Comment: Thanks for answering it. I was looking for this. I am not sure why your answer is not top one.

Answer (score 3):

First read [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

> Means Delta Degrees of Freedom.  The divisor used in
> calculations is `N - ddof`, where `N` represents the number of elements.
> By default `ddof` is zero.

Searching for [Degrees of Freedom](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)) then explains the statistical concept (emphasis mine):

> Estimates of statistical parameters can be based upon different
> amounts of information or data.  The number of independent pieces of
> information that go into the estimate of a parameter are called the
> degrees of freedom.  In general, the degrees of freedom of an estimate
> of a parameter are equal to the number of independent scores that go
> into the estimate minus the number of parameters used as intermediate
> steps in the estimation of the parameter itself (**most of the time the
> sample variance has `N − 1` degrees of freedom, since it is computed
> from N random scores minus the only 1 parameter estimated as
> intermediate step, which is the sample mean**).

Answer (score 0):

It refers to denominator degrees of freedom

In some cases (e.g. working with population level data) your denominator is N. In other cases (e.g. sample level data) your denominator is N-1 (or whatever your ddof value is set to).

So the difference here is do you want to divide by N, or divide by N-ddof? Where and when you divide by each is a more domain/context specific question

In numpy, the default is ddof = 0 (divide by N), so if you want a different denominator value you have to manually specify it

Answer (score -1):

ddof = 1 refers to [Degrees of Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28statistics%29).

It's a statistical concept.

The formula for Standard Deviation of population:

[image]

But most of the time, we are trying to use sample Standard Deviation to estimate the true Standard Deviation of population. The formula above is a downward-biased estimation, using N-1 instead of N gives us a correction.

Check wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation for more information

Comment: I thought `ddof` means "**delta** degrees of freedom": how many degrees to subtract. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html